# Reason for ID3 "Bright colored fish"?

Tags: production, format

I noticed that ID3 has a list of types of images that can be embedded in an audio file:

> The TYPE must be one of the following: OTHER, ICON, OTHER_ICON,
> FRONT_COVER, BACK_COVER, LEAFLET, MEDIA, LEAD_ARTIST, ARTIST,
> CONDUCTOR, BAND, COMPOSER, LYRICIST, RECORDING_LOCATION,
> DURING_RECORDING, DURING_PERFORMANCE, VIDEO, BRIGHT_COLORED_FISH,
> ILLUSTRATION, BAND_LOGO, PUBLISHER_LOGO.

That’s from the help screen of eyeD3, but [many web pages](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=BRIGHT_COLORED_FISH%20ID3) mention it without reference to ID3

Most of them have a use I can understand.  **But why "BRIGHT_COLORED_FISH"?**  In the [cited web search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=BRIGHT_COLORED_FISH%20ID3), I found several mentions, including two Reddit posts asking the same question, but no answer.  Adding "why" to the search got the same results.

I couldn’t find an appropriate tag.

Answer (score 6):

Upon following your search link, I found that the **BRIGHT_COLORED_FISH** image type is also shared with the Ogg Vorbis format.  This gives an immediate answer!

The [Ogg container format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogg) and [Vorbis codec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorbis) are maintained by the [Xiph.org foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiph.Org_Foundation), which takes its name from *[Xiphophorus hellerii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_swordtail)*, the Swordtail fish.

The real fish looks something like this:

[image: Xiphophorus hellerii]

([image source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Xiphophorus_helleri_Annanasschwerttaeger_Maennchen.JPG))

Its depiction in the logo of Xiph.org is this:

[image: Xiph.org logo]

So I think the answer is, quite literally, a brightly-colored fish.

Edit, in response to PiedPiper's comments:

Admittedly, my explanation is a long shot.  To be fair, I did call it an "immediate answer", not a thoroughly-researched plausible one.

But, the [ID3 tag is defined by a standard without a standards body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3#:%7E:text=ID3%20is%20a%20de%20facto%20standard%20for%20metadata%20in%20MP3%20files%3B%20no%20standardization%20body%20was%20involved%20in%20its%20creation%20nor%20has%20such%20an%20organization%20given%20it%20a%20formal%20approval%20status).  The [id3.org](https://id3.org) website has been down for years. Even when it was up, it apparently [didn't explain the meaning of "a bright coloured fish"](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-spec-tacular-failure/#:%7E:text=A%20bright%20coloured%20fish), or much else for that matter.

The [surviving specification on github](https://github.com/id3/ID3v2.4/blob/master/id3v2.4.0-frames.txt) doesn't explain.

It's almost certainly an inside joke by the author.  Maybe they were a fan of Captain Beefheart's *Trout Mask Replica* and wanted a picture type just for that.

[image: Trout Mask Replica Album Artwork]

Comment: Where in the ogg/vorbis documentation is this found?

Comment: @PiedPiper It's on the xiph.org site at a few places, e.g.: [1](https://svn.xiph.org/websites/opus-codec.org/docs/opusfile_api-0.5/structOpusPictureTag.html#:~:text=A-,bright%20colored%20fish,-Illustration), [2](https://xiph.org/flac/format.html#:~:text=bright%20coloured%20fish), [3](https://xiph.org/flac/api/group__flac__format.html#:~:text=A%20bright%20coloured%20fish). I'm sure there could be other reasons; this seems like an inside joke either way.

Comment: All of those are just references to the existing ID3 format, that's not evidence that the Xiph people had any influence on that format.

Comment: Fast and Bulbous!

Comment: One of the web pages I looked at claimed (or implied) that this was in ID3 before Xiph or Ogg existed.  So, it could be that Xiph picked that logo because it was in the spec.  Or it was added to the spec at Xiph's request (or to accomodzte Xiph putting it in files in spite of the spec).  I was unable to find an actual specification.  One link that claimed to be wasn't.

Comment: Agreed, it's an inside joke, but who did it?Xiph has existed since about 1994, the ogg vorbis format since about 2000. The fish reference has been in the ID3 spec since at least 1998 (it's in id3v2-00 dated March 1998). The most likely culprit for putting it in is Chris Montgomery, the founder of Xiph who had been working on multimedia formats since about 1993.

Comment: Reminds me of HTTP status code 418, which means [I'm a teapot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/418)

Comment: @Glorfindel ...of course [teapots have a long history in computer graphics inside jokes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utah_teapot).